# Visual Studio 2010 "Solution platforms" popup missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, toolbar

I'm getting a weird problem with Visual Studio 2010 Premium. I use two PCs, on the first there is no problem on the second the "Solution Platforms" popup menu disappeared, the configuration is the same (Windows 7 x64). The problem occured when I opened a project from a mercurial repo, I was not able to restore the popup. I reset the Visual Studio settings and done a Repair from the installer. No change. If I create an blank project (framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0) the "Solution Platforms" popup is still missing.
Also if I change the target platform with Build --> Configuration Manager there is no effect on the build (no compilation for x86 for example).

Any ideas (no full reinstallation please ) ?

thank you.

ps : [Screenshot of the bug](http://andrew.free.fr/lksjdqiojsd/VStudioNotWorkingToolbar.png)

André

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following:

- From the list, select "Customize..."
- On the screen that appears, click the
  "Add Command..." button.
- Select "Build" from the Categories
  list, then scroll to "Solution
  Platforms" in the Commands list and
  click "OK"

Close the dialog and check your list, it should now be available.

Comment: By the way, I believe this is caused by choosing "primarily C# development" when you first run visual studio 2010. If you choose C++ it is where you expect if you previously used vs 2008 (correct me if I'm wrong about this). However, I prefer to work with the C# settings and then go back and add this combo-box/command as described in the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is the wrong way to restore the platforms combobox. What you should do is find the little dropdown menu next to the configuration combobox and choose "Add/Remove buttons" From that list, check "Solution Platforms" and everything will be in its rightful place :)

Comment: Your answer didn't work for me because `Solution Platforms` wasn't available in my "Add or remove buttons" list. I had to select "Customize" as depicted in the accepted answer

Comment: that's strange. I can see the choice in every version of Visual studio  I have (2010,12 and 13). The accepted answer makes no sense if you consider that you're trying to enable existing buttons, not add random commands to a toolbar. Are you sure you are looking at the right dropdown ?

Comment: @a_mole As others have reported, it appears to depend on which development option you choose when installing VS (primarily C#, General, etc).  The OPs question is directly about re-adding the button that you say should already be there